# Converting integer to integer array in c

Tags: c, type-conversion

How do I convert an integer value to integer array format?

For example:

```
int answer = 140;
```

and expected value that I wish to get is:

```
int arr_answer[] = { 1, 4, 0};
```

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many digits are in `answer`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to generate source code with the required output `int arr_answer[] = { 1, 4, 0};`? Please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of digits ahead of time (in this case 3), you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int numDigits = 3;
    int answer = 140;
    int digits[numDigits];

    int i = numDigits - 1;
    while (answer > 0)
    {
        int digit = answer % 10;
        answer /= 10;
        digits[i] = digit;
        printf("digits[%d] = %d\n", i, digits[i]);
        i--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
digits[2] = 0
digits[1] = 4
digits[0] = 1
```

Comment: `0 4 1` is wrong. Fix your code. It should be `1 4 0`

Comment: @Michi it's not wrong, it's filling the array in reverse.

Comment: @bejado : the size of integer is not given... thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

One option is to count the digits and use a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int ans = 140;
    int x = ans;
    size_t i, size = 0;

    while ( x ) {
       x=x/10;
       size++;
    }

    int arr_answer[size];

    for ( i = size - 1, x = ans ; x ; x = x/10, i-- ) {
       arr_answer[i] = x % 10;
    }

    for ( i=0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
       printf("%d ", arr_answer[i]);
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you can use fixed size array which is sufficiently large, you don't need to calculate `size` and thus avoid the first loop.
But this is probably the only to make an *exact size array*. Alternatively, you can also use `malloc()` (if you don't need to use an *array*) to allocate a block of memory if the number of digits are potentially huge (and you'd need to store them differently as well - an `int` can hold limited range of values).

<sup>1</sup> VLAs, which are available since C99, are optional feature in C11.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C programmer, so I can't give specific code, but I'd try 1) integer to string conversion (Google says try sprintf()), 2) run a for loop for the length of your integer/string and assign to an array. I'd end up doing something like this:

```
integer_String = convertToString(integer)
for (integer_String.length()) {assign to array}
```

Probably nice to wrap it up in a function that returns the array.

EDIT: Disregard haha other answer is way better.

Comment: You can delete your answer if you want people to disregard it.

Comment: I mean, it could still be useful. I've definitely learnt a lot from sub optimal answers on questions; just about different possibilities and methods.

Comment: @jylyn I agree, if you want to leave it then you shouldn't tell people to disregard it, just let it stand for itself.